# Having trouble getting zebra rows and tablesorter to work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

By zebra rows, I am talking about the table design where the background color of rows alternate in color. By table sorter, I am talking about the Jquery plugin that makes table headers clickable. When clicked, the table is sorted by that particular table header. Here is the website for it: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

My problem:
When a user sorts the table by clicking on a table header, the zebra rows do not work anymore.

Here is my code when a user clicks on a table header:

```
  $("th").click(function() {
    $("table").trigger("update");
    enableRowHover();
    $("table").tablesorter();
    enableZebraRows('tbody tr:odd td', 'alt');
  });
```

Here is my code that enables the zebra rows:

```
function enableZebraRows(selector, className) {
  $("tr").removeClass("alt");
  $(selector).removeClass(className).addClass(className);
}
```

The function that enables zebra rows works well because on document ready, I use it, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your zebra rows aren't correct after you sort.

You could just call enableZebraRows after you have sorted the table:

```
$("table").bind("sortEnd",function() {
    enableZebraRows(tbody tr:odd td', 'alt');
});
```